# hadoop hive insert query to insert all rows of one table to another table

Tags: hive

i want to insert all rows of one hive table to another hive table

```
insert into table <table_name> as select * from <table_bkp>
```

i have many rows in  table but it is inserting only one row from  to  
Please suggest the solution for it

and i am using hive 1.2.1 version

Answer (score 3):

In your query remove 'as' and write the query as follows

```
insert into table <table_name> select * from <table_bkp>
```